# Deep linking from Notification - how to pass data back up through the backstack?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link, android-navigation-graph

In my app, the user can select a category, then select an item within that category to finally view the item details. The standard/forward flow is:

> `SelectCategoryFragment` -> `SelectItemFragment` -> `ViewItemDetailsFragment`

On selecting a category, the `selectedCatId` is passed via a `Bundle` from `SelectCategoryFragment` to `SelectItemFragment`:

```
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(v);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(SelectItemFragment.ARG_CATEGORY_ID, selectedCatId);
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_nav_categories_to_items, args);
```

`SelectItemFragment` will then use the `getArguments().getLong(ARG_CATEGORY_ID)` value to query and display the appropriate items from the selected category.

That works fine. But I am now trying to implement deep linking when the users taps on a Notification, jumping them straight to `ViewItemDetailsFragment` with a backstack that can take them up to `SelectItemFragment`, then `SelectCategoryFragment`.

My problem is that, as described, `SelectItemFragment` depends on the `ARG_CATEGORY_ID` argument being passed to it in order to retrieve/display its data. I've read up on [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#java) and [nested navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs), but don't really know how to pass `ARG_CATEGORY_ID` with deep linking/backstacks.

Is there a tidy way I can pass data from `ViewItemDetailsFragment` to `SelectItemFragment` when the user presses back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TLDR***: problem might be solved using nested graphs. Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/proper-back-stack-on-android-every-time-4a811f8ab78c) for more details.

### Longer answer

Let's define simple fragment `FragmentRed`, `FragmentGreen` and `FragmentBlue` who inflate simple layouts each with corresponding background color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And declare fragment classes as such:

```
class FragmentRed : Fragment() {

    private val args: FragmentRedArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.red, container, false)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = args.foo.toString()
        return view
    }
}
```

`FragmentGreen` and `FragmentBlue` are copy pasted, but substituted all color texts with corresponding color texts, i.e. `FragmentRedArgs` -> `FragmentBlueArgs`, `R.layout.red` -> `R.layout.blue`.

Let's declare main activity layout as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Where `main_graph` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_red">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_red"
        android:name="com.playground.FragmentRed">
        <argument
            android:name="foo"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            app:argType="integer" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_red_to_fragment_green"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_green" />
    </fragment>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/secondLevel"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment_green">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_green"
            android:name="com.playground.FragmentGreen">
            <argument
                android:name="bar"
                android:defaultValue="0"
                app:argType="integer" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment_green_to_fragment_blue"
                app:destination="@id/fragment_blue" />
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_blue"
            android:name="com.playground.FragmentBlue">
            <argument
                android:name="zar"
                android:defaultValue="0"
                app:argType="integer" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

Now inside `MainActivity` let's spawn a new notification, passing in arguments for each of fragments: "foo" (red) - 1, "bar" (green) - 2, "zar" (blue) - 3.

Our expectation is upon clicking on notification to open Blue screen with text 3, upon back click see Green screen with 2 and another click should bring Red screen with 1 on the screen:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val pendingIntent = navController.createDeepLink()
            .setGraph(R.navigation.main_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.fragment_blue)
            .setArguments(bundleOf("foo" to 1, "bar" to 2, "zar" to 3))
            .createPendingIntent()

        createNotificationChannel() // outside of the scope of this answer
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel")
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("content text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setChannelId("channelId")

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(100, builder.build())
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the actual behavior on device:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. So, basically, the Bundle passed into `setArguments()` when creating the PendingIntent is automatically passed up the backstack?

Comment: I believe so. But please don't ask what happens if two different fragments have same name for input argument.