# How to use SafeArgs with destination that appears more than once in navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I had the main navigation of my app set up nicely using SafeArgs. This was my **nav_graph.xml**:

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@+id/fragment1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment1"
        android:label="Fragment 1">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment2" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment2"
        android:label="Fragment 2">
        
        <argument
            android:name="ARG_CATEGORY_ID"
            app:argType="long"/>

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment2_to_fragment3"
            app:destination="fragment3" />
            
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment3"
        android:label="Fragment 3">
        
        <argument
            android:name="ARG_ITEM_ID"
            app:argType="long"/>
        
   </fragment>

</navigation>
```

And, using SafeArgs, I could happily navigate from **Fragment2** to **Fragment3** using:

```
NavDirections navDirections = Fragment2Directions.fragment2ToFragment3(myItemId);
navController.navigate(navDirections);
```

However, I then needed to add deep linking capability from notifications (having a backstack with arguments, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476437/1617737)), so I added a sub `<navigation />` element to the end of **nav_graph.xml** - which became:

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@+id/fragment1">

    <fra8gment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment1"
        android:label="Fragment 1">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment2" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment2"
        android:label="Fragment 2">
        
        <argument
            android:name="ARG_CATEGORY_ID"
            app:argType="long"/>

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment2_to_fragment3"
            app:destination="fragment3" />
            
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="org.example.Fragment3"
        android:label="Fragment 3">
        
        <argument
            android:name="ARG_ITEM_ID"
            app:argType="long"/>
        
    </fragment>
   
    <!-- This is the new sub navigation block that provides a backstack-with-arguments. -->
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/nav_notification"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment2Notif">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2Notif"
            android:name="org.example.Fragment2"
            android:label="Fragment 2">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/fragment2Notif_to_fragment3Notif"
                app:destination="@id/itemsGraph" />

        </fragment>

        <navigation
            android:id="@+id/itemsGraph"
            app:startDestination="@id/fragment3Notif">

            <argument
                android:name="ARG_ITEM_ID"
                app:argType="long"/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment3Notif"
                android:name="org.example.Fragment3"
                android:label="Fragment 3">

                <argument
                    android:name="ARG_ITEM_ID"
                    app:argType="long"/>

            </fragment>

        </navigation>
        
    </navigation>
   
</navigation>
```

Notice that the file now contains two occurrences of `org.example.Fragment2`.

This has brought me a new problem in that the second occurrence of `org.example.Fragment2` (ie, **fragment2Notif**) has resulted in the original `Fragment2Directions.fragment2ToFragment3(...)` method being no longer available.

It's been replaced with `Fragment2Directions.fragment2NotifToFragment3Notif(...)` which works fine when in the notification part of my app but, when called from the main part of my app, as expected, results in:

> IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
> org.example:id/fragment2Notif_to_fragment3Notif is unknown to this
> NavController

It seems SafeArgs has overwritten the first **Fragment2Directions** object, meaning the only method it has is `fragment2NotifToFragment3Notif(...)`.

So, how do I get the old `fragment2ToFragment3(...)` method back?

I expect I could solve the problem by subclassing **Fragment2** to effectively duplicate it with a different name, ***Fragment2Notif***, then using **Fragment2** in my main nav and **Fragment2Notif** in the sub nav, but is there a more elegant/preferred way?

Comment: Hi! Is this a runtime or compile exception?

Comment: It's a runtime exception, but is fully expected/understandable. The main issue is the `fragment2ToFragment3()` method being lost.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your `nav_graph.xml` file, I think the idea for nested graphs(series of destinations grouped within the parent navigation graph, in this case with id `nav_main`) is to add deep linking capability from notifications (having a backstack with arguments).

Other than this, with the assumption that the `fragment2ToFragment3(...)` is overwritten to  `fragment2NotifToFragment3Notif(...)` by SafeArgs plugin, there is no significant change as one can still navigate to `Fragment3` using `fragment2NotifToFragment3Notif(...)` since the two nested navigation graphs combined have same structural content as the parent navigation graph except for id attribute of the `<fragment>` tag.

So, in essence using `fragment2NotifToFragment3Notif(...)` instead of `fragment2ToFragment3(...)` won't hurt for this case.